# select random group of observations (rows) from grouped data

Tags: r, dplyr

I have repeat observations for two individuals spanning four years. How can I select all of the observations from a single year randomly?

```
set.seed(123)
    dat <- data.frame(IndID = rep(c("AAA", "BBB"), each = 100),
                      Year = sample(c("2001", "2002", "2003", "2005"),200, replace = T),
                      Value = rnorm(200))
dat$Value[dat$IndID == "AAA" & dat$Year == "2002"] <- NA
dat$Value[dat$IndID == "BBB" & dat$Year == "2005"] <- NA
```

Note, the differing sample sizes between individual-year combinations.

```
table(dat$IndID, dat$Year)

      2001 2002 2003 2005
  AAA   26   27   20   27
  BBB   20   30   30   20
```

Also note that not all years have data.

```
dat %>% group_by(IndID, Year) %>%
  summarise(NoDat = sum(is.na(Value))) %>%
  as.data.frame()
  IndID Year NoDat
1   AAA 2001     0
2   AAA 2002    27
3   AAA 2003     0
4   AAA 2005     0
5   BBB 2001     0
6   BBB 2002     0
7   BBB 2003     0
8   BBB 2005    20
```

I have seen a number of helpful examples for selecting specific rows within a group (i.e. top, last, n random, etc.) but am not connecting the dots on how to select all rows within a group. Here I want all of the data for a randomly-selected year for each individual, preferably with `dplyr`. The random year should be specific to each individual given differing periods with and without data. The random year needs to be one with observations collected, which varies among individuals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(IndID = rep(c("AAA", "BBB"), each = 100),
                  Year = sample(c("2001", "2002", "2003", "2005"),200, replace = T),
                  Value = rnorm(200))
rand_year <- sample(dat$Year,1)
dat %>%
   filter(Year == rand_year)
```

And here is the edited version where you get random year for each participant (note that year could be the same):

```
result <- dat %>%
   group_by(IndID) %>%
   filter(Year == sample(Year, 1))
```

And replacing `filter()` row with `filter(Year == sample(unique(Year[!is.na(Value)]), 1))` will give the same probability for each year to be selected and exclude missing values as mentioned in comments.

Comment: I had not thought of working outside of `dplyr`. I have added specifics to the question and the data set, specifically adding `NA`s to some years. I need the random year to be different for each individual.

Comment: slick. Could also change line 2 to `filter(Year == sample(Year[!is.na(Value)], 1))` to filter out years with `NA`.

Comment: Oh, yes. Good point, because I am sampling a vector with uneven sample sizes, the probability will not be equal. This is fine for this example, but appreciate the comment.